# Why do we need voidify function template in uninitialized_copy

Tags: c++, templates, function-templates

I was reading about [`std::uninitialized_copy`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/uninitialized.copy#2) and came across something called `voidify`:

> Effects: Equivalent to:
>
> ```
> for (; first != last; ++result, (void) ++first)
> //#1----vvvvvvv----------->what does this call to voidify mean here
>  ::new (voidify(*result))
>    typename iterator_traits<NoThrowForwardIterator>::value_type(*first);
> ```

Upon further looking for [`voidify`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/specialized.algorithms#4), I came to know that it is a function template:

> Some algorithms specified in this clause make use of the exposition-only function voidify:
>
> ```
> template<class T>
>  constexpr void* voidify(T& obj) noexcept {
> //#2------vvvvvvvvvv-------------------------------->why does this const_cast to void* is needed
>    return const_cast<void*>(static_cast<const volatile void*>(addressof(obj)));
> //#3------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^------------->why this static_cast to const volatile void* is needed
>  }
> ```

So as we can see that `voidify` returns a `void*` to `obj` or something else I don't quite understand as there are some casts involved and i don't know why they are needed. I've placed comments indicating my doubts. Can someone tell me in steps why is `voidify` needed in `new (voidify(*result))` and why are the `const_cast` and `static_cast` needed.

In summary(just to clearly state my doubts) my questions are:

1. Why do we need to call `voidify` in `new (voidify(*result))`. I know that this is using palcement-new but I don't know the reason for calling `voidify` and passing `*result` as an argument and then using the return value for placement-new.
2. Why the `const_cast` is used here. Why not some other cast like `reinterpret_cast` or `static_cast`. That is what is the need of choosing `const_cast` here.
3. Why is the `static_cast` used here instead of some other cast.
4. Why can't we just write `return addressof(obj);` or `return (void*)(addressof(obj);`.

Note that I am trying to understand how the `equivalent to` version works. The reason I asked my question in different parts is because I think that dividing it in individual steps and then understanding those individual steps lets us understand a topic better. At the end of the day I want to know how does the [`equivalent version`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/uninitialized.copy#2) work.

Comment: Also note that a `reinterpret_cast` cannot be used to add/remove `const` (or `volatile`) qualifiers.

Answer (score 3):

> Why do we need to call voidify in new (voidify(*result)). I know that this is using palcement-new but i don't know are we calling voidify and passing *result as an argument and then using the return value for placement-new.

The first thing to point out is that in a lot of cases the code would work without `voidify`, so if your intuition imagines it working without voidify, this is why.  The `voidify` is there to guard against the situation where there are multiple overloaded versions of `operator new`, and one of them would be selected over placement new `operator new(size_t, void*);`

> Why the const_cast is used here. Why not some other cast like reinterpret_cast or static_cast. That is what is the need of choosing const_cast here.
>
> Why is the static_cast used here instead of some other cast.

If you want to be sloppy, you could also just do this with a single C-style cast, as in:

```
return (void*) addressof(obj);
```

But each of `const_cast` and `static_cast` does something different, and you could potentially need either or both types of conversion.  You could replace `static_cast` with `reinterpret_cast`, but it wouldn't buy you anything and could make it harder to catch certain bugs, so at that point you might as well use the C-style cast.

> Why can't we just write return addressof(obj); or return (void*)(addressof(obj);.

The former will fail unexpectedly if you happen to have an overloaded `operator new(std::size_t, decltype(addressof(obj))`.  The later (C-style cast) is perfectly fine as previously mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

Voidify() takes an address of an object that may be `const`, `volatile`, or both and creates just a `void*`. This can't be done directly with just one type cast since it requires both the removal of qualifiers and casting to `void`.

But it can be done in two steps. `static_cast` can cast to a `void*` but can't remove qualifiers. However, it can add any that aren't already there. Hence `static_cast<const volatile void*>`  The next step is to use `const_cast<void*>` which removes the qualifiers leaving just a `void*`

Using these two casts has an additional benefit. It's valid code in a `constexpr` function. `reinterpret_cast` is not usable in `constexpr` functions.